# Avoid interpolation of discontinuities for periodic data

Tags: gnuplot

I have a complex-valued data file and I want to plot the phase information separate from the absolute values in a flat pm3d plot. I defined a cyclic color palette between `-pi` and `pi` like this

```
set palette model HSV
set palette define (-pi 0 1 1, pi 1 1 1)
set palette maxcolors 1000
```

i.e. I assign the two 'reds' on the rim of the HSV color wheel to the end points of the phase domain (±pi). I then go about to plot the data like this:

```
set pm3d map
set cbrange [-pi:pi]
splot 'datafile' w pm3d
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Phase plot with apparent discontinuity at +/- pi]

As you can see, there is an artifact in places where the phase value jumps from -pi to pi as the plot algorithm interpolates the two opposite values, yielding a color close to 0 (cyan). Is there a way to avoid this artifact *from within gnuplot*? Of course, I could always manipulate the data in a way that avoids a discontinuity and assigns phases outside the standard `[-pi:pi]` domain but I'd rather not.

---

**EDIT:**
You can reproduce a plot similar to the above one with a function instead of a data file:

```
I = {0,1}
set xrange [0:3]
set yrange [0:3]
set isosample 100
splot arg(exp(I*x*y)) w pm3d
```

Comment: It could help if you link your data file so that potential helpers can do some testing.

Comment: Good point. I added a minimal example based on a complex function. Shouldn't make any difference for the solution to my problem if it's a data file or a function.

Comment: Actually, the structure of your data can make a difference. If your data is given at regular points in a mesh, you can use `with image` instead of `pm3d`, which has several advantages.

Comment: Right now, the data are given as triples of x, y, and z. But x and y are drawn from a regular mesh, so I could change that easily. How would `with image` evade the problem?

Comment: Because `with image` does not interpolate. So you get a dot at each grid site with the color corresponding to the z component. If your mesh is sparse this will not look nice. But if your grid is sufficiently dense, I guess this will look more or less like what you want.

Comment: The mesh is dense, alright, but not necessarily commensurate with the resolution of the gnuplot plot. Also, the x direction is much more dense than the y direction.

Comment: If you replace your edit's `splot ...` by `plot "++" u ($1):($2):(arg(exp(I*$1*$2))) w image` you'll see that your problem goes away. But again, whether this solution works for you or not depends on your data file's structure and sampling density. There are ways to interpolate using `set dgrid3d` but this might not fix your problem.

Comment: Ok, so I tried it for my data and it gives decent enough results. The anisotropic sampling rates lead to some weird looking effects once the phase starts to oscillate more rapidly. I'd still be interested in an answer that does not sacrifice interpolation, since in principle interpolation across the ±pi boundary could be defined in a meaningful manner. Still, I'd encourage you to post your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I insist as in my comments that usually it's a better idea to, whenever possible, do color map plots using `with image`, especially because with vector-image terminals the (non) compression of `pm3d` can lead to very large image sizes. However, you have a very specific situation because you want interpolation. I have explored the different options of `set pm3d corners2color` which determines how the interpolation between neighboring grid sites is done. Some of the options might get your rid of the problem, judge by yourself:

```
set palette model HSV
set palette define (-pi 0 1 1, pi 1 1 1)
set palette maxcolors 1000
set pm3d map
set cbrange [-pi:pi]
I = {0,1}
set xrange [0:3]
set yrange [0:3]
set isosample 100

unset tics
unset colorbox

set term pngcairo size 640,4096; set output "out.png"
set multiplot layout 9,1

do for [mode in "mean geomean median min max c1 c2 c3 c4"] {

eval "set pm3d corners2color ".mode

set title mode            
splot arg(exp(I*x*y)) w pm3d not

}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, now why doesn't gnuplot's `help` explain the `corners2color` option? Thanks a lot for your troubles.